# Run .NET 2.0 applications for Win

Tags: wine, mono

I am trying to run application for Windows on Ubuntu 11.10

I tried

```
wine /path/to/file.exe
```

Error is:

```
wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.
```

I  have mono(seems to be not Mono for windows)

```
mono /path/to/file.exe
```

gives me error:

```
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
It should have been installed in the `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try installing mono for windows or try .NET for windows with winetricks. In a shell try:

```
winetricks dotnet20
```

and

```
winetricks mono28
```

Comment: Got this error:
`fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA "C:\\users\\yasin\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\" 00000000
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f31c,0x00000001,0x33f344) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x451d7c`
@Andrei: who cares about what you want? The OP wants wine.

Comment: Fixed this error above by deleting `~/.wine directory`.

Comment: Error: Cannot install on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I found the fix to my 64bit problem and was ready to write it in an answer, BUT THIS QUESTION IS PROTECTED...

Comment: "This product is not supported on a 64-bit operating system."

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar problem on 12.04, and this is what i did:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

and then

```
mono /path/to/file.exe
```

that's it!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I found that installing `mono-complete` did not allow my application (CloudBerry Explorer) to function, as it was looking for configuration files that running via Mono did not properly find.

I'm running on a x64 system, which .NET 2.0 won't install on (see http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3754), so I found that I had to remove my wine directory and do:

```
export WINEARCH="win32"
winetricks dotnet20
```

(Alternatively, you could set a different `WINEPREFIX` for the application with a `win32`  architecture, but I had no need for that kind of separation of environments, and nuking my previous setup was perfectly acceptable.)

At this point I wanted to run `winetricks mono28` but winetricks has not yet been updated to account for Novell removing the file from their mirror (see http://code.google.com/p/winetricks/issues/detail?id=221). I used the proposed solution in the ticket:

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.8/windows-installer/9/mono-2.8-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-9.exe
wine mono-2.8-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-9.exe
```

(This took about 30 minutes to download as the mono-project.com servers do not have the same kind of juice that Novell had, sadly...) It allowed the application I wanted to use to run (it has some issues but I think that's more about Wine support than it is the .NET support).

Comment: Wow, 2-years later and winetricks still hasn't been updated. Is winetricks abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

Mono for Wine can be installed via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-mono4.5.6\*
```

which would provide MS .NET compatibility compatibility layer.

See [Mono](http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) page at Wine for more details.