# Online activiation within wine, port 80

Tags: wine, internet

I have a program that I simply received as an .exe file. Installation *seems* to work with wine but it asks to activate the product online. The preset is to use the Internet Explorer settings but as I don't have neither Windows nor the Internet Explorer I am stuck. There is a setting to route the request via a proxy server and port 80 but I have no idea what to make of it.

How do I activate this port to use within wine?

[image]

I have tried to uncheck the Use Proxy Server box with the same result:

[image]

I opened up a terminal to track what wine is doing, navigated to the .exe file and started it. The activation screen occurs (picture 1). Here is the output:

> fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 0x136a78 (0x156af8)
>   fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 0x136a78 (0x156af8)
>   fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
>   p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x33fdcc): stub
>   fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0x204d6 0x00000000
>   fixme:x11drv:sync_window_opacity LWA_COLORKEY not supported
>   fixme:font:RemoveFontMemResourceEx (0x8771dcc9) stub
>   fixme:font:RemoveFontMemResourceEx (0x877df699) stub
>   fixme:wtsapi:WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0x204d6

Comment: Can you access [the activation server](http://license.pe-international.com/lpweb3/lpws.asmx) if you put the address into a browser? I tried it from here. It's slow but it worked. If that doesn't work for you there might be an actual networking issue. If it does work, then it's probably a bug in Wine.

Comment: That does work with Firefox and with the Internet Explorer within wine. So it guess it is an issue with wine running the program activation.

Answer (score 0):

Wine probably has installed a version of Internet Explorer 6. You may find it by browsing to the following location (.wine is a hidden directory which can be shown in Nautilus by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>:

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer
```

There you may find the following icon ready to run by clicking:

[image]

Alternatively try to execute it with the following command:

```
 wine '/home/<username>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe'
```

This will open Internet Explorer in Wine, from where you can access the registration site (hopefully in your locale - shown here is a German locale):

[image]

Comment: Will OP have to install `.NET` (based on the ASP.Net in your image)?

Comment: This does work (it also points me to the German version), however I need to connect to the server with the program shown in the screenshots above (to active it). Maybe I better try with a virtual box. Thank you!

Comment: @vasa1: they will probably **not** have .NET installed - at least here it was not installed (just have checked this with winetricks). In case they need it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69744/run-net-2-0-applications-for-win

Comment: @boo2060: the activation app may need another Windows component to run. Hard to say which one it might be.